# How to make an automatically click

Tags: java, android

please guide me
I want to know How to make an  automatically click on a web link  inside web view in my android application?

Comment: what do you want? Autotest or do it programmatically inside the app?

Comment: @sia121 You can go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4075955/2293534

Comment: i want using  programmatically inside my app

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708453/how-to-automatically-click-a-button-in-android-after-a-5-second-delay

Answer (score 0):

As [Lee Chou stated](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-script-my-Android-app-to-click-on-a-link-or-button-inside-a-WebView),

Use Javascript to handle the "clicking" in the Webview:

1. Extend WebViewClient to handle onPageFinish
2. Check if the url is correct
3. Run the javascript code with webView.loadUrl("javascript:" +
   jsClickButton)

> Caution: This method is very fragile, so this is not recommended
>   unless the site is your own.

You can also go through from here: http://howtrick.com/make-android-website-app-using-web-view-android-studio/